# How does gfdiv differ from "\" for Galois field in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, division, galois-field

I two variables **YDataVector** and **diff** which are **(255 x 1 gf)** that is Galois vectors. I need to do division between the two variables like for real numbers

```
YDataVector = ( YDataVector - 1 ) / diff;
```

I found that there is also the command **gfdiv**, which divides elements of Galois fields.

**Which kind of operator is *\* in Galois Field in Matlab?**

So which division operator should I use **gfdiv** or **\** in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`gfdiv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfdiv.html) performs element-wise division whereas `gf/mldivide` (`\`) is akin to matrix division (i.e., solving linear systems or inverting matrices). `gfdiv` appears to be a special case of `./`, particularly if `P > 2`. See [this MathWorks article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/error-detection-and-correction.html#fp8058) for further details.

Comment: So they both return the same result, but the inner algorithm differ and thus their speed differ. Is this right?

Comment: @Masi, `gfdiv` and `./` (`gf/rdivide`) should both return the same results if `P = 2`. The documentation says to use the latter for GF(2^m). You can see the code for `gfdiv`: just type `edit gfdiv` in your command window.

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day and opened my world here! Now, I can see the code of those Matlab functions. So much easier to look directly to the code and think what it does.

Comment: Glad to help. That works unless functions are mex compiled or `pcode` encrypted. Sometimes you'll find a file has nothing but the help in it. Also, classes like `gf` and `sym` overload many functions and operators, so you can often prefix either the help or the edit trick I showed you with the class name, e.g., `gf/rdivide` which you'll see is calling the mex function `gf_mex` (there's help for it, but no code). Also, if you come across a function called from a file that you can't find using the above methods, it may be in a private folder: try something like `edit private/func_name`.

Comment: I want to find the code or documentation of the command **YDataVector.x**. Do you know where the documentation of this command **.x** are?

Comment: @Masi: I'm guessing that `class(YDataVector)` is `gf`. The constructor for the class is just `gf` so you can view the code with `edit gf`. The `x` just extracts the `x` field from the `gf` struct object.

Comment: Where do you see that **x** juts extracts the **x** field from the **gf**?

Comment: When you create a `gf` object with, e.g., `a = gf(ones(2,2))`, the line `p.x = uint32(x);` in the `gf` constructor (line 67 in R2013a) sets the `x` field. Then `b = a.x` extracts the field. `class(b)` is `uint32`.